# Hotkey Toggling between Private & Non-Private browser window?

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari, shortcut

Consider two Safari windows: one private, the other not.  There may be more than one tab in the window.  The goal is to toggle between the two windows (not the tabs) with a hotkey.

Does such a hotkey exist?

Comment: how do you have  Safari widows open

Answer (score 1):

You'll find that shortcut in `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > (left side of window:) Keyboard > Focus on next window`.

With my (German) keyboard default is `Cmd-<`, but that may be different with other system languages. Just look there!

BTW: I changed this shortcut to a more convenient `Ctrl-<` which (on my keyboard) is easier to reach.